# What is the equivalent of web.xml's <env-entry> tag when using ServletContainerInitializer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0, spring-java-config

I'm trying to replace my web.xml file with a code based class that extends from Spring's WebApplicationInitializer.  My web.xml file has a couple "env-entry" elements.  I'm trying to figure out how to set these in my WebApplicationInitializer class, but with no luck.  Perhaps someone knows the code equivalent of these tags?

```
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.setConfigLocation("WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml");

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("springmvc", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/*");

        //How do I add this?
        //  <env-entry>
        //      <env-entry-name>logback/configuration-resource</env-entry-name>
        //      <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        //      <env-entry-value>logback.xml</env-entry-value>
        //  </env-entry>    
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `InitialContext context = new InitialContext(); context.addToEnvironment("logback/configuration-resource","logback.xml)";`

Comment: Thank you @kolossus.  It was the correct answer.  Reference can be found here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html.  An <env-entry> is a scalar JDNI resource.  I am using Spring, and have decided to define the value in the composition root instead of as a JNDI resource.

Comment: Haha. That's nice. I'll undelete my answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<env-entry>` just declares essentially a web app context attribute, something you can bind yourself with `ServletContext#setAttribute()` that you already have there

```
   servletContext.setAttribute("logback/configuration-resource", "logback.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.  After some time I ended up finding a solution and posted it to a similar stack overflow post and including here in case it helps any one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66109551/2441088

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 web.xml is still up and running and handles env-entries perfectly. Instead using large web.xml which boostraps the whole app, just use those parts of web.xml which are relevant to your need. Do not use metadata-complete="true" and absolute-ordering within web.xml as those will interfere with classpath scanning. Following web.xml works perfectly with spring boot:

```
<web-app id="example" version="3.0"
    xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <env-entry>
        <description>As an example of env-env usage, let set spring profiles</description>
        <env-entry-name>spring.profiles.active</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>universe</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>

    <env-entry>
        <description>Answer to the life the universe and everything?</description>
        <env-entry-name>answer</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.Long</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>42</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>

</web-app>
```

Envivorment entries are fully available from spring context.

```
@Configuration
public class UniverseConfiguration {

    @Profile("universe")
    @Value("${answer}")
    Long answer;

}
```

In short, web.xml isn't deprecated and removed. It is just that with ServletInitalizers it isn't required anymore. During application bootstrap, webServer will still scan for web.xml.