# logback JNDI selector is not loaded in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I have a issue that blocked me for days.
I explain: i have 2 apps share one server. I call them appA and appB. We use Spring framework and we use logback for the logging system. I configured the logback JNDI context selector, as explainning in the doc: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/contextSelector.html . and i set the logback file as: logback-appB.xml and logback-appA.xml in the server. It works well..

But now we migrate the appA to spring boot, and the appB stay in spring. I dont know why the appA can not load the JNDI context name that i configured in the web.xml:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>logback/context-name</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>appA</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

then i debuged the line 54 in the class ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.ContextJNDISelector:  contextName = JNDIUtil.lookup(ctx, "java:comp/env/logback/context-name"); the result is aways null. I dont know why, is the Spring boot force to use their context?

I think maybe i can use the logging.config to force use the logback config file
with these try
logging.config=Z:/DEV/...../logback-appA.xml,  or logging.config=file:Z:/DEV/...../logback-appA.xml or
logging.config=classepath:logback-appA.xml, none of them can load the file. debug in the line 67 of the class org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem, the String configLocation is aways null.

even i set the logging.config=Z:/DEV/...../logback-spring.xml, il can not be loaded.

i think i can't use the spring Active profile, as the appB do not use spring boot.

The version of spring boot is 2.1.7. If some one can help, thanks so much.

Comment: the add of -Dlogging.config in the JVM, worked, but i dont want this solution, becaus the JVM impact the second APP

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and after days of searching this link proved to be most helpful:
http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2013/03/renamed-logback-config-file-for-web.html

In your spring initializer you can override onStartup to add a custom listener:

```
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    // Add the customer listener to configure logback
    servletContext.addListener(CustomServletContextListener.class);
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
  }
```

and then implement a custom listener which loads the logback configuration:

```
public class CustomServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
    // Get the war/context name from this context event
    String contextName = contextEvent.getServletContext().getContextPath().substring(1);

    // Get the path of the logback configuration file
    URL configFileURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("logback-" + contextName + ".xml");

    // If the URL exists in the classpath
    if (configFileURL != null) {
      try {
        // Reset the existing logger context and set the name to match the current context
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        loggerContext.reset();
        loggerContext.setName(contextName);

        // Update the logger context and configure the logger based on the configuration file
        JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
        configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
        configurator.doConfigure(configFileURL);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```